# Getting 401~UNAUTHORIZED when trying to console.log the message I have received from a socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to create a web site that only shows how much $ is a bitcoin worth in real time ( meaning the $ price should change every second ). For this I'm using https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/ Web Socket which uses socket.io. So far my code is this:

```
var ioClient = require('socket.io-client');

var cryptocompare = ioClient.connect('wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com')

var subscription = '5~CCCAGG~BTC~USD';
cryptocompare.emit('SubAdd', { subs: subscription });
cryptocompare.on('error', console.error)
cryptocompare.on('m', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Unfortunately, I get 15 lines of 401~UNAUTHORIZED, 1 line of 5 and 1 line of 3~LOADCOMPLETE. Not sure what does that mean.

Comment: what 's wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com ???

Comment: That's the web socket of cryptocompare to which I have to connect.

Comment: May be you need the appid to connect to that api or some register info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subs` need an `Array`, not a `String`.

```
     cryptocompare.emit('SubAdd', { subs: [subscription] });
```

Comment: Yep, didn't see that. Thanks a lot.